# VS2015 steps over "User Code" while VS2013 does not

Tags: visual-studio

I have a unit test dll that references function dll.
When I used VS2015(Enterprise) to debug, breakpoint in unit test was hit, but the breakpoint in function was not.

The message from output window is:
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'function dll namespace + method name'

Debug->Windows->Modules shows the function dll has been loaded with "User Code" Yes; Optimized "NO"; Symbol Status: "Symbols loaded"

This problem doesn't happen on VS2013. Does anyone know the new change from VS2013 to VS2015 please?

The function dll references some other dlls that was built using MSBuild, which I am not sure the version number. Is this probably a reason?

Answer (score 2):

You should disable "Just My Code" option in VS. Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General and disable "Enable Just My Code"

Comment: Could you explain why? Both unit test and function dlls are all "my code".

Comment: I just tried, this doesn't work unfortunately. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My VS2015 unit tests would not run in debug mode and disabling this caused them to run again. Thanks!